# ¿Cómo surgió la expresión 'ni qué ocho cuartos'?

Tags: etimología, modismos, historia

La expresión '(...) ni qué ocho cuartos' se usa para hacer más notoria una negación. Revisando en ngrams y en el CORDE, al menos se está escribiendo desde finales del siglo XVIII, pero el origen de la expresión no me es claro

Comment: Pues en el NTLLE no aparece la expresión, aunque sí está recogida actualmente [en el DLE](https://dle.rae.es/cuarto#CyZ9nkb): "Usada para subrayar el desacuerdo con algo, disconformidad que previamente se ha expresado de una forma exclamativa."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parece ser una expresión que se usa mucho en México (y también en Puerto Rico y en Colombia), y hay varios periódicos mexicanos que conjeturan que la expresión viene de Espana en el siglo XVIII, debida a una subida de precios que hizo que muchas cosas empezaran a costar más de ocho cuartos de peseta (un "realillo"). Esto habría llevado a discusiones en los mercados que darían origen a esta expresión. La fuente con más referencias que he encontrado, en el periódico *El Horizonte*, [dice](https://d.elhorizonte.mx/opinion/editorial/ni-que-ocho-cuartos/1813189)

> Por muchos años, en España existió “el realillo”, que era la moneda de uso corriente y equivalía a ocho cuartos de peseta. Por eso también era conocido como “realillo de a ocho cuartos”. Para muestra y respaldo de lo dicho, va una antigua copla española: “Tengo que empedrar tu calle, con realillos de a ocho cuartos, para que vayas a misa, sin romperte los zapatos”.
>
> Al parecer, para la economía popular de los Siglos XVIII y XIX, pagar ocho cuartos por los artículos de primera necesidad era lo considerado razonable y cuando los precios superaban esta referencia, el descontento popular se manifestaba con grandes protestas. En un fragmento de la obra Granada la Bella, que Ángel Ganivet escribió en 1896, hallamos noticia de este hecho: “En lo antiguo, el pan era caro en pasando de ocho cuartos la hogaza mejor o peor pesada; se sufría refunfuñando a los nueve y diez cuartos; se insultaba al panadero al llegar a los 11 o 12, y en subiendo de ese punto, venía la revolución”.
>
> La expresión “ni que ocho cuartos”, apareció en este ambiente, con mucha probabilidad en la primera mitad del Siglo XVIII, por supuesto, en tierras españolas. La documentación más antigua conocida está en los diálogos de un entremés llamado La Avaricia Castigada, escrito en 1761 por Ramón de la Cruz. De ahí estas líneas: “¿Ayala, amigo? – Qué amigo, qué Ayala, ni qué ocho cuartos. Ya es otro tiempo, señores. ¡Que hasta aquí me han atisbado!”.

La referencia de 1761 es muy anterior a la más antigua que aparece en la Hemeroteca Digital de la BNE, que es de *[El Látigo liberal contra el Zurriago indiscreto](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0003711029&page=8&search=%22que%20ocho%20cuartos%22&lang=en)* en 1821:

> y  nada  mas,  que  lo  demás   es  broma  ,  qué  alma,   ni   qué   ocho  cuartos.

Comment: Además de México, al menos en Puerto Rico y Colombia también se utiliza la expresión de manera habitual, por lo demás, la respuesta es toda tuya